# Como clonar o repositório e todos os braços do remoto?

Tags: git

Gostaria de saber como clonar automaticamente todos os braços do remote para o local, sem precisar ficar fazendo o comando abaixo para cada um.

```
git checkout -b <branch> <remote>/<branch>
```

São muitos braços para poder fazer isso um a um.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro que seja criado o alias abaixo, que executa o checkout para todos os branches remotos. O nome de cada branch no local será igual ao branch remoto.

```
git config --global alias.clone-branches '! git branch -a | sed -n "/\/HEAD /d; /\/master$/d; /remotes/p;" | xargs -L1 git checkout -t'
```

Criado o alias, basta executá-lo assim:

```
git clone-branches
```

Comment: Isso vai ser muito útil para mim. Às vezes o repositório mirror entra em conflito com o remoto que uso para desenvolvimento

Comment: Acabei de passar por isso, Jefferson! Por isso decidir colocar essa questão e responder!

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra maneira de executar seria utilizando o comando **git ls-remote**

Este comando lista as referências do repositório remoto, por exemmplo:

```
git ls-remote --heads origin
```

O retorno será a lista de remots do repositório atual.

Usando uma simples linha de comando em Powershell é possível baixar os branchs:

```
git ls-remote --heads origin | % { $_ -match 'refs/heads/(.*)' | out-null; $matches[1] } | % { git checkout $_ }
```

Se quiser saber os detalhes leia o [post](http://www.egomesbrandao.com.br/2016/04/05/git-powershell-baixando-todas-branchs-apos-clonar-um-repositorio/).

Answer (score 1):

`git clone <repo>` e depois um `git fetch origin` (ou qualquer nome que tiver dado). Assim teu local tem todas branchs do remoto.

Comment: Legal você querer ajudar, mas você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata.

Comment: Eu dei uma solução ao problema dele, isso é uma resposta, não?

Comment: Alterei a resposta pra manter só a resposta. Entendi agora.

Comment: Valia aí o ponto negativo por causa disso?